# How to hide <pre> and <table> content from auto-generated excerpts?

Tags: theme-development, excerpt, the-content, conditional-content

Auto-generated excerpts just take the first x characters from the post content and cut that off at a certain point.

When there is a `table` or `pre` element in that part, the excerpt looks rather useless most of the time. How can I hide the content of these elements from my auto-excerpts?

Comment: Or, better yet: just use a **user-defined** excerpt. Why user-defined excerpts remain such an underused feature, I have no idea...

Comment: @ChipBennett I forget that often. And for pages there is by default no excerpt box, but an excerpt can happen in search results.

Comment: Search results is an interesting edge case. I would recommend either enabling Excerpts for pages, or else customizing `search.php` and changing the loop output conditionally based on post type.

Comment: @ChipBennett Yes, you can do that for pages. Custom post types on the other hand are … unpredictable.

Comment: Ideally, whatever registers the CPT would filter search results index query output via `pre_get_posts`. :) (Thus concludes my Pollyanna-ish view of WordPress development for today.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To filter the content only when an auto-excerpt is generated you have to chain the hooks:

1. Hook into `get_the_excerpt` and register a filter for `the_content`.
2. In the second filter remove both elements and their content before the excerpt can see it.

Sample:

```
add_filter( 'get_the_excerpt', 't5_excerpt_clean_up', 1 );

/**
 * Register handler for auto-generated excerpt.
 *
 * @wp-hook get_the_excerpt
 * @param   string $excerpt
 * @return  string
 */
function t5_excerpt_clean_up( $excerpt )
{
    if ( ! empty ( $excerpt ) )
        return $excerpt;

    add_filter( 'the_content', 't5_excerpt_content' );

    return $excerpt;
}
/**
 * Strip parts from auto-generated excerpt.
 *
 * @wp-hook the_content
 * @param   string $content
 * @return  string
 */
function t5_excerpt_content( $content )
{
    // Remove immediately; maybe the next post doesn't 
    // use an excerpt, but the full content.
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__ );

    // Fails with nested tables. Just don't do that. :)    
    return preg_replace( '~<(pre|table).*</\1>~ms', '', $content );
}
```