# Hide specific content from excerpts

Tags: content, excerpt

I am using Inked Blog to generate lists of articles on a page. However, I need to remove a specific headline (with the class `sow-headline-container`) from the excerpts. This is a bit of a struggle, but using the code from [How to hide <pre> and <table> content from auto-generated excerpts?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/96777/how-to-hide-pre-and-table-content-from-auto-generated-excerpts) I managed to remove the headline. However, this resulted in all post excerpts on the page to be the same. Anyone has any clue to why this is happening?

I am using Wordpress 4.5.3 with a custom theme based on Customizr 3.4.2.1 as well as the Inked Blog from Page Builder by SiteOrigin 2.4.10

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've found the answer myself through a lot of Googling :)

If anyone else is struggling, this [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/XMJNtH6A) provides a solid solution for stripping out headings from the excerpts. The solution was provided by Michael at [the Wordpress Support Forum](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/remove-content-within-the-header-tags-in-the-excerpt?replies=7).